# Get the unread reply from Slack Api

Tags: slack, slack-api

Currently there is not a direct method in the slack api to fetch the unread replies over a thread. To get the replies on a conversation we have to pass the timestamp of that particular threaded conversation using `conversation.replies`. So I want a method where we can get all threads where replies are unread.

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly documented API to do that.

Comment: I know that. But i wanted this feature. Is it possible with anything else that you might know.